# Parsing a datetime string in python containing micro and milliseconds?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

How do I parse a datetime string that looks like:

```
2015-11-01 10:10:00 00:10:00
```

So far I have:

```
date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(line, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %f')
```

But then I get an error,

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: :10:00
```

And this is because it is not sure what to do with the rest of the datetime string because there is more than just microseconds there. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you need the leftovers? If not, hack'em out `line[:-6]`...

Comment: Hi, sorry if it is a standard I'm not familiar with but can you explain the final 00:10:00? How is this related to fraction of a second (including micro/milliseconds but also tenths and hundredths)?

Comment: Yeah I really don't need the leftovers so I did just cut them off! Thanks!

Comment: Aren't this a range of time? Like date start end?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime( df['x'] )` seems to work fine here without specifying the last '00:10:00'.  I'm not sure if it is just ignoring the last bit or not...